# WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function get_tensorlists at ...> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Spyder 4.0.1, when I run the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def get_tensorlists(m,n,max=7):
  list1 = tf.random.uniform([m,n],0,max,seed=0)
  list2 = tf.random.uniform([m,n],0,max,seed=0)
  return list1,list2

@tf.function
def get_dataset(X,Y,epochs):
  set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,Y))
  # adjust it the way we need
  set = set.shuffle(100).repeat(epochs).batch(1)
  return set

temp = get_tensorlists(10,1)
X = temp[0]
Y = temp[1]
dataset = get_dataset(X,Y,1)

print(dataset)
i = 0
for (x,y) in dataset:
  i+=1
  print(i)
  print(x,y)
```

I get this error print:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function get_tensorlists at 0x000001DA9852C798> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is.
Please report this to the AutgoGraph team.
```

The only suggestion I found is to install `pip install gast==0.2.2` and restart Spyder. But that didn't change anything for me.

So, how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I'm not getting any warning with TensorFlow 2.2.0-rc4 in CPU (my gast version is 0.3.3)

Comment: Which Spyder version do you use?

Comment: I do not use Spyder, I just tested your code in a standalone IPython console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

- Uninstall TensorFlow by manually deleting every single file that contains "tensor" in it (and belongs to TensorFlow)
- Uninstall gast using `conda uninstall gast`
- Reinstall TensorFlow using `conda install tensorflow`
- Reinstall TensorFlow using `conda install gast`

The error doesn't appear anymore now.

---

Besides that, the output I get is still senseless and not what should be printed.
I've finally also solved the output problem, I hade to downgrade TF: `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0`

**EDIT:** I wouldn't recommend anyone to delete the files manually, that usually causes a whole lot of trouble - although it worked for me here.

Answer (score 0):

**The Newer version of gast causes the warning, to resolve:**

```
conda install 'gast==0.2.2'
```

*or if you are using pip*

```
pip install 'gast==0.2.2'
```